# What is an efficient way to check if a name exists in sqlalchemy, python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

currently I'm using a for loop to check if a record exists,

```
def IsUserPrivileged(name):
  namequery = Ops.query.all()
  for names in namequery:
    if name == namequery.name:
      return True
    else:
      return False
```

So theres a database of ops with an Id field and a name field. I'm looking for something if this (I know this is wrong syntax):

```
def IsUserPrivileged(name)
  namequery = Ops.query.filter_by(name =name).first()
  if namequery:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

But this throws an error.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
def is_user_privileged(name):
    namequery = Ops.query.filter(name==name)
    if namequery.count():
       return True
    else:
       return False
```

But you can optimize your function further:

```
def is_user_privileged(name):
    namequery = Ops.query.filter(name==name)
    return namequery.count()
```

In Python, the general practice is to use InitialCaps for classes, and for functions lower case with underscores. For more in this, see the [python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names) also called by its Python Enhancement Proposal (PEP) number, PEP8.